# I am trying to run sway window manager on an alpine docker image. It runs however showing me some erros. I can't run it using docker compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am using alpine latest as a base docker image and I installed sway on it somehow I am able to run it using the following commands but I get some errors.
These are the commands I use to get it running:

```
docker run -it  -e  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/Raju \
           -e WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 \
           -v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/$WAYLAND_DISPLAY:/home/Raju/$WAYLAND_DISPLAY  \
           --user=Raju \
            -e WLR_LIBINPUT_NO_DEVICES=1 \
          compose-sway sway
```

Even though it runs but gives me the following errors:

[error messages][1]
Errors are attached in the screenshot as well as here:

```
00:00:00.040 [wlr] [render/wlr_renderer.c:322] drmGetDevices2 failed: No such file or directory
00:00:00.040 [wlr] [types/wlr_drm_lease_v1.c:705] No DRM backend supplied, failed to create wlr_drm_lease_v1_manager
2022-10-15 23:48:27 - [main.c:340] Found config * for output WL-1 ((null))
00:00:00.014 [swaybar/tray/tray.c:42] Failed to connect to user bus: No such file or directory
```

However, when I try to run it using docker-compose it gives me the following errors and sway window manager doesn't even launches.
Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  sway:
    image: compose-sway                           
      - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/Raju/ 
      - WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 \
      - --user=Raju \
      -  WLR_LIBINPUT_NO_DEVICES=1 \
    command: /bin/sh -c "unset DISPLAY && exec sway  "
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 8081:5900
    volumes:
      -  $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/$WAYLAND_DISPLAY:/home/Raju/$WAYLAND_DISPLAY
```

Here are the errors from docker-compose:

[docker compose errors.][2]

```
sway_1  | 00:00:00.001 [wlr] [backend/wayland/backend.c:550] Could not connect to remote display: No such file or directory
sway_1  | 00:00:00.001 [sway/server.c:56] Unable to create backend
compose_sway_1 exited with code 1
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help me with this please
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knyib.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYtdE.png

Here's how my docker file looks:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add alpine-conf 
RUN apk update 
RUN apk add build-base 
RUN apk add eudev 
RUN apk add ttf-dejavu
RUN apk add seatd
RUN apk add sway sway-doc
RUN apk add xwayland  
RUN apk add foot     
RUN apk add bemenu   
RUN apk add swaylock swaylockd 
RUN apk add swaybg 
RUN apk add swayidle
RUN apk add rofi
RUN apk add waybar
RUN apk add dbus
RUN apk add wofi
RUN apk add elogind polkit-elogind
RUN apk add wayvnc
RUN apk add mesa-dri-gallium
RUN apk add libva-intel-driver
RUN apk add xdg-desktop-portal
RUN apk add xdg-desktop-portal-wlr

RUN     adduser Raju -D -G wheel
RUN   adduser Raju input
RUN   adduser Raju video

COPY xdg_runtime_dir.sh root/etc/profile.d/xdg_runtime_dir.sh
RUN  /bin/sh -c "mkdir -p root/.config/sway"
RUN /bin/sh -c " cp /etc/sway/config root/.config/sway/config"
RUN chmod a+s /etc/sway/config
USER Raju
EXPOSE 5900 


CMD dbus-run-session -- sway
```

I followed this link:

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Sway

Maybe I am missing something I am not sure.

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the error message.  Conversely, there seems to be a lot of things in the Dockerfile that probably aren't necessary to reproduce the problem (and some incorrect `ENV export` and `RUN /bin/sh -c` lines).  Can you [edit] the question to include only a [mcve], removing the unnecessary things, fixing the incorrect syntax, and making sure to include the error message as plain text directly in the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze Please have a look now. I even posted a bug report on swaywm official github account reporting the errors and asked if it was possible to run sway inside a docker container on an alpine image. The Swaywm maintainer said it doesn't supports on docker however even with errors I am able to launch sway. I was hoping if the same docker commands could work in docker compose to run even with errors but docker compose file is not able to make the container run sway.

Comment: A Docker container only runs one process; `Failed to connect to user bus` suggests it's expecting some other one (a DBus daemon).  Would this process be easier to run directly on your desktop, or in a virtual machine with a standard display environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze that error can be removed. The other two errors I am struggling with solving. Its easy in both virtual machine and desktop. But I guess no one has ever tried installing sway on alpine docker image as I cannot find any useful resources anywhere on the internet

Comment: @DavidMaze the dbus error can be resolved by adding dbus-run-session -- sway at the end instead of sway. The docker commands when written in terminal launches sway with errors. However the same commands in docker file don't launch sway , they just show only errrors